# How to Create comparison bar graph

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have below mentioned datafram:

```
Month    Fig1    Fig2
Mar-17   10      12
Feb-17   25      18
Jan-17   10      15
Dec-16   11      18
Nov-16   10      15
```

I want to create a colorful bar graph for this, i have tried below mentioned code but it didn't work.

```
bargraph <- ggplot(data = df1) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Month,
                y = value,
                group = variable,
                color = variable)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

and further i want to store that graph in `JPG` or `PNG` to send it through `mailR`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified your code as below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  gather(Fig, Value, -Month) %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, 
                        levels = c("Nov-16", "Dec-16", "Jan-17", "Feb-17", "Mar-17"))) %>%
  arrange(Month)

bargraph <- ggplot(data = df2) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Month,
               y = Value,
               fill = Fig,
               color = Fig),
           stat = "identity",
           position = position_dodge()) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
bargraph
```

[image]

To use `ggplot2` to plot a group bar chart, we need to convert `df1` from wide-format to long-format, as `df2`. And then, it is necessary to reorder the `Month` column because that determines the order on the x-axis. Therefore, I converted the `Month` column to factor and use `arrange` to reorder it.

In `geom_bar`, we need to specify `stat = "identity"` and `position = position_dodge()`. It is possible to use `geom_col` to create the same plot without `stat = "identity"`.

To save the plot, we can use the `ggsave` function. You can specify the file directory in the `filename` argument.

```
ggsave(filename = "bargraph.jpg", plot = bargraph)
```

Finally, using [mailr](/questions/tagged/mailr) is really a completely different question. Please search for related questions on Stack Overflow. If you could not find the information you need, then you can consider to ask a new question.

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "Month    Fig1    Fig2
'Mar-17'   10      12
                  'Feb-17'   25      18
                  'Jan-17'   10      15
                  'Dec-16'   11      18
                  'Nov-16'   10      15",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Getting this error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Value' not found`

Comment: @Rahulshah I could not reproduce this error. Please make sure you load all the packages I specified in my example.

Comment: Thanks...it worked. Just wanted to know why the `png` image is not showing in gmail.

Comment: I think this is because of its size how to keep the graph size (i.e height and width ) small.

Answer (score 0):

## Overview

Transform `df` into a wide matrix - one column for each value in `df$Month`, one row for each non-`df$Month` column - prior to using it inside of [`barplot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/barplot.html).

Since `df$Month` is given as an abbreviated month-year format, the [`as.yearmon()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-1/topics/yearmon) function from the [zoo](/questions/tagged/zoo) package was used to order the matrix in chronological order prior to plotting.

[image: PNG of Barplot]

## Reproducible Example

```
# load necessary packages
library( zoo )

# load data
df <-
  read.table(
    text = "Month    Fig1    Fig2
Mar-17   10      12
    Feb-17   25      18
    Jan-17   10      15
    Dec-16   11      18
    Nov-16   10      15"
    , header = TRUE
    , stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

# create complementary color scheme
color.scheme <- c( "#18A4D2", "#D24618" )

# store non-Month column indices
non.month.column.condition <-
  which( !colnames( df ) %in% "Month" )

# transfrom Month to a 
# yearmon class using the zoo package
df$Month <- 
  as.yearmon( x = df$Month, format = "%b-%y" )

# reorder the data frame by 
# chronological order
df <-
  df[ order( df$Month ), ]

# transform df
# to wide matrix
# one column for each value in df$Month
month.values.by.fig <-
  lapply(
  X = df[ , non.month.column.condition ]
  , FUN = function( i )
    tapply(
      X = i
      , INDEX = df$Month
      , FUN = function( j )
        j
    )
)

# collapse values into one matrix
month.values.by.fig <-
  do.call(
    what = "rbind"
    , args = month.values.by.fig
  )

# plot and save the results
png(
  filename = "fig_value_by_month.png"
  , units = "px"
  , height = 1600
  , width = 2400
  , res = 300
)
barplot(
  height = month.values.by.fig
  , beside = TRUE
  , col = color.scheme
  , border = NA
  , legend.text = TRUE
  , args.legend = list(
    x = "topleft"
    , bty = "n"
    , border = NA
  )
  , las = 1
  , ylim = c( 0, 30 )
  , xlab = "Month-Year"
  , ylab = "Values"
  , main = "Values Over Time, by Figure Type"
)
# shut down plot device
dev.off()

# end of script #
```

Comment: you have hard coded the value of `ylim = c( 0, 30 )` but it could be anything based on dataframe.??

Comment: @Rahulshah, `ylim` sets the minimum and maximum limits of the y-axis. Feel free to change it to whatever you would like based on the data, such as `ylim = c( 0, max( month.values.by.fig ) )`